# i am unable to run sonarqube on the EC2 instance

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sonarqube

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:07 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:07 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /usr/local/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2g -Xms2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.2.5.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process12186382016905612213properties
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:26 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2023.07.11 15:46:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

executed 
$SONAR_HOME/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console
```

but getting the above error.